# Deviance vs Predictive Power of a variable in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, deviance

I have a question. I have a logistic regression model with two variables a & b. In the analysis of deviance table (type = 2) seems that variable b is more significant than a. But when I plot the logistic curve it seems that a has the plot:
[image]

and b: [image]

How is that possible? I feel I missing something.